# ε environment of number 1

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, limsup-and-liminf

I am stuck with a problem it asks me to find the $\epsilon$ environment of the number $X=1$ and find for which $\epsilon$.
I got a few intervals to solve for, here are the intervals: $(0,2) , (\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3}), [-1,3)$

I have no idea which $\epsilon$ environment am I allowed to choose, for the first interval $(0,2)$ is it correct to write $(X-\epsilon,X+\epsilon) ?$ I don't understand the problem how am I suppose to find the $\epsilon$ environment without using limits ?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you just meant to find which $\epsilon$ was used in each case?  Thus, we take $\epsilon =1$ and see that the interval $(0,2)$ can be written as $(1-1,1+1)$?  Something else?

Comment: I don't understand It well myself, I think I must find if there exists  $\epsilon$ environment  for each case ... I would say that for the interval $[-1,3) $ there doesn't exist $\epsilon$ because $\forall \epsilon>0$ from the limit theory.

Comment: I bet the question is just asking you, for each of the intervals, find the value of $\epsilon$ that makes the interval equal to the interval from $1-\epsilon$ to $1+\epsilon$. Nothing at all to do with limits or limsups or liminfs, just a little arithmetic.

Comment: The interval $(-1,3)$ corresponds to $\epsilon = 2$.

Comment: So, do you understand now, Nobody?

Comment: Yes I do, I didn't understand the meaning of $\epsilon$ environment and that I could choose arbitrary  $\epsilon$. Should I delete this question now or leave it like this ?

Comment: I would suggest that now that you understand it, you should write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.

Comment: Never mind, I've done it myself.

Comment: I apologize, didn't login to StackExchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\epsilon$ environment of $X$" means the open interval from $X-\epsilon$ to $X+\epsilon$. So, if $X=1$, then $(0,2)$ is the $\epsilon$ environment of $X$ for $\epsilon=1$; $(2/3,4/3)$ is the $\epsilon$ environment of $X$ for $\epsilon=1/3$; $(-1,3)$ is the $\epsilon$ environment of $X$ for $\epsilon=2$.

I'm not sure what to make of the half-open interval $[-1,3)$ in the question.